# Can not run exe file on pc without Qt installed

Tags: qt, exe

I am really stuck! I have searched all around on the internet for a solution but still cannot resolve the problem.

I have an windows app that runs on the PC where Qt is installed properly. I cannot run it elsewhere though. I have put the following dlls next to the executable:

```
D3DCompiler_43.dll
icudt51.dll
icuin51.dll
icuuc51.dll
kernel32.dll
libEGL.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libGLESv2.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
msvcp100.dll
msvcrt.dll
qgif.dll
qico.dll
qjpeg.dll
qminimal.dll
qmng.dll
qoffscreen.dll
qsqlite.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Sql.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
qtga.dll
qtiff.dll
qwbmp.dll
qwindows.dll
```

... but when I run the executable file I keep receiving error message box saying the application has requested the Runtime to terminate...

I have created directories such as qt/qt50.1/5.0.1/mingw47_32/plugins/platfroms, imageformats, sqldrives and moved the relevant dlls there. I get the same error message again and again. Is there any way out other than trying to compile the Qt?

Comment: You can try to use Dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to get the list of depending and missing dlls. Maybe this tool could hint something useful.

Comment: which version of Qt, are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem before, and I found an ugly answer on net for it, but it worked

you should create a directory and rename this directory to **platforms**

then copy the 2 following Dlls in this folder

```
qminimal.dll , qwindows.dll
```

copy platforms to your dlls folder

at the end you have something like this

```
platforms
D3DCompiler_43.dll
icudt51.dll
icuin51.dll
icuuc51.dll
kernel32.dll
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It really worked! I have had made a directory named platforms but in c:/Qt/..../platforms. it should have been made in exe file directory and now my app is running with no error message. QT is really a very good C++ programing environment but this shared library aspect and tricky way of getting things done really sucks I think they should consider some improvements in this area.