# Qt apps are not running outside of Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm not able to execute the .exe file form the debug or release folder outside of Qt.

I have followed the suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672858/can-not-run-exe-file-on-pc-without-qt-installed) and copied `qminimal.dll , qwindows.dll` to a platforms folder together with the executable but nothing happens when I click on the .exe. No error messages or anything. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

According to **Dependency Walker** I need these files to run the .exe

I do have all these files in the same folder and still nothing is happening.

[image]

Comment: Try to analyze your EXE file with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: See more suggestions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency).

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html

Comment: Because that's actually what you need to know (in particular, look under "Creating the application package"). About Dependency Walker, you have to expand the Qt5Widgetsd.dll and Qt5CoreD.dll nodes to see in turn *their* dependencies; also, you have to actually run your application from inside dependency walker to see runtime-loaded dlls. Finally, you should do this job just with the "release" executable.

Comment: Assuming you're on Windows, I'd take a wild guess: could you go in Computer > Computer Management and look at the application event logs ? There might be an error that could help you figure out what causes your app to not start properly.

Comment: You're trying to run debug build on a machine that doesn't have debug crt libraries installed.

Comment: Remember that debug builds are not redistributable.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618%28v=vs.110%29.aspx